# Full Length URL "edit" using NSMakeRange

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsurl, nsrange

I'm trying to cut a URL down from this:

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/01/edward-snowden-russia_n_3688225.html

to this:

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/

using `NSMakeRange(Location, Length)`

My code:

```
if ([URLContainer hasPrefix:@"http://www."]) {            
    NSLog(@"URL Detected");

    NSUInteger Location = 0;            
    NSUInteger Length = 29;

    NSString *URLCutDown =  [URLContainer substringWithRange: NSMakeRange(Location, Length)];

    Label = URLCutDown;
}
```

My problem is that I don't quite know how to make the end of `Length` stop at the forward slash (`/`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use [NSURL's](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) `baseURL` method:

```
NSString * baseURL = [URLContainer baseURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting with a range you should use the methods of `NSURL` such as `host`, `scheme`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly cunning solution:

```
NSURL *startingPoint = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2013/08/01/edward-snowden-russia_n_3688225.html"];
NSURL *result = [[NSURL URLWithString:@"/" relativeToURL:startingPoint] absoluteURL];
```